# Change action on Spring form:form submit

Tags: javascript, spring, forms

I've done a lot of searching to see if this question has been asked already without luck.  It seems it should be a fairly straight forward thing...

I want to change the value of my 'action' on the Spring form when submitting.  The value of action will be determined by which button is clicked.

I am hoping someone can explain why my approach doesn't work, and secondly what is the best way to do what I'm after.  Thanks.

Here is my form with the buttons.  I'm trying to have the button's onclick change the action.

```
<form:form id="userForm" method="POST" commandName="user" action="/">
    <input type="submit" value="Add"    onclick="document.getElementById('userForm').action='${pageContext.request.contextPath}/user/add'"/>
    <input type="submit" value="Delete" onclick="document.getElementById('userForm').action='${pageContext.request.contextPath}/user/delete'"/>
</form:form>
```

The outcome is that the form does not get submitted.

Answer (score 0):

OK, I have resolved this question myself as a PICNIC.

The form works just fine.  The issue was elsewhere in my page.  I had changed my page to import a header.jsp file which contains the taglib definitions.  However, I used `<jsp:include page=` instead of `<%@ include file=`.

Comment: Here is a good explanation of the difference between the two includes: http://beginnersbook.com/2013/12/difference-between-include-directive-and-include-tag-in-jsp/